# kafka version 2.12-2.8.8 The message was out of order due to message retry

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to use a producer to specify a fixed partition, asynchronously send five data to the topic, msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4, msg5, but the second data, msg2, is retried because of a network problem. Finally, the data order of this partition `msg1`, `msg3`, `msg4`, `msg5`, `msg2`.

I wrote demo, and by setting iptables rules, and can not achieve, so I need help, the following is my code

```
public class MyKafkaProducer1 {

    static {
        ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) iLoggerFactory;
        Logger root = loggerContext.getLogger("root");
        root.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.227.103:9092");
        props.put("acks", "1");
        props.put("delivery.timeout.ms", 6000);
        props.put("retries", 2);
        props.put("retry.backoff.ms", 30000);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("request.timeout.ms", 5000);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", 5);

        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("testTopic", 0, "key" + 1, Integer.toString(1)), (metadata, exception) -> {

            if (exception != null) {
                //code
            }
            if (metadata != null) {
                //code
            }
        });

        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("testTopic", 0, "key" + 2, Integer.toString(2)), (metadata, exception) -> {

            if (exception != null) {
                //code
            }
            if (metadata != null) {
                //code
            }
        });

        producer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's your problem? You're only sending 2 records here, not 5? There's no good way to test that exactly message 2 will fail without mocking and actually injecting the failure, since it's all asynchronous (message 2 could be flushed and message1 could fail instead). Don't depend on external network rules or firewalls

Comment: Hello, the above code is just an example, even if I send 10 messages, I can not make one of them fail to retry, and the order will be disordered after retry. Do you have a code demo for my reference

Comment: Unless the simulation and actual injection failed?
I don't know what to do

Comment: I don't have any example code that wouldn't otherwise be in the Kafka unit tests themselves

Comment: Okay, I'll go check out kafka unit testing